# What is the advantage of using maclaurin expansion of functions like tan(x) over using the functions themselves?

Tags: taylor-expansion, trigonometric-series

For example, using the maclaurin series of tan(x) instead of tan(x) has the disadvantage that the series and the function agree only for a very small neighbourhood around 0 and for that very small value of x, we can rather use the trigonometric limit,
{limit (x ->0)} tan(x) = 0 
What is the point of using the expansion then?
How do we find the exact domain where these functions match with their respective maclaurin expansions?

Comment: The coefficients of the Maclaurin series of the tangent have a nice combinatorial interpretation, which you totally miss if you just compute values of the function.

Comment: How exactly do you compute $\tan x$? Except for special values there's no exact way. So you need some kind of approximation. For $\tan$, the series is not a very good approximation. But you can approximate $\sin$ and $\cos$ and take the quotient.